# iOS 8 Container View Controller children rotation

Tags: objective-c, ios8, rotation

I have a custom container `UIViewController`.
The container contains two children `UIViewControllers`.
I need to disable rotation for one of them.

Documentation states:

> By default, rotation and appearance callbacks are automatically
>   forwarded to children.

But `-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate` got never called for children.

How to disable rotation for child view controller in **iOS 8**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question could do with some more detail to be certain what you are trying to achieve. Here's an answer, but given the question is a little vague I might have made some wrong assumptions.

The method you refer to, `-shouldAutoRotate`, only applies to the top-level viewController's view. The subviews do not rotate, relatively speaking. But they may adjust themselves according to the new layout.

What you probably do want to do is counterrotate the 'static' view, so that it maintains a fixed aspect with respect to the screen.

The doc you are quoting from is referring to these methods (pre-ios8)

```
– willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:
– didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:
```

in ios8 they are deprecated and replaced with

```
- viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:
```

If you use this method, you will have to check the orientation from `[UIDevice currentDevice]` and make the counter-rotation adjustment (which would be a rotation transform) to suit.

If this doesn't work out for you, it is always possible to make a custom view and have it (or the viewController) register for device rotation notifications. For this you would send `beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications` to `[UIDevice currentDevice]` and then register for those notifications with the notification centre:

```
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
           addObserver:self 
              selector:@selector(deviceOrientationDidChange) 
                  name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

*edit*

> *"what about frame?"*

What *about* frame? It's not relevant here. You will be applying a rotation transform to your 'non-rotating' view. Apple advises never to get or set the frame property after transforms have been applied, as the numbers no longer make sense. You can set bounds and centre properties instead, or - possibly better - use autolayout constraints <del>or autoresizing mask</del> to get your result.

*edit2*

Here is an (animating) example using `viewWillTransitionToSize`:

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator {

     UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = 
       [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
     CGAffineTransform transform = 
      [self transformForOrientation:deviceOrientation];
     CGPoint center = 
        [self centerForOrientation:deviceOrientation];
     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        self.rotatingView.center = center;
        self.rotatingView.transform = transform;
}];   
}
```

where `transformForOrientation` will return the appropriate rotation transform, and `centerForOrientation` will return a centre derived from the original unrotated view's centre coordinates.

Using `viewWillTransition` enables you to take control of the rotation *before* the interface has rotated to the new device orientation. At this point `UIDeviceOrientation` will give you the correct destination orientation, while `UIInterfaceOrientation` will still return the pre-rotated aspect. If you need really tight coordination between animations, you can use a UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator object.

Comment: Constraints makes sense to me, I can dynamically change height/width constant. But autoresizing mask? I always thought that affine transform applies after layout.

Comment: @orkenstein - yes, autoresizing was a wrong suggestion, I have corrected it.

Comment: Thanks. Status bar still spoils the whole thing, but I've got some new ideas.

Answer (score 1):

In the view controller

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Comment: This won't work if another viewController is returning a contradictory response at the time

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can.  When the application queries a viewController for supported orientations it only polls one of them and then makes a transform on the entire window.  The best I can suggest is a affine transform on the container view of the viewController in question in order to reverse/compensate the rotation.